# How to show that a d-degenerate graph on n vertices has at most $d*abs(n)$ edges?

Tags: graph-theory

I think I'm still slightly confused on the definition of a d-degenerate graph as it is. Some places says that a graph is d-degenerate if all of its subgraphs have a vertex pf degree at most d, and some say all of its INDUCED subgraphs which I believe is different?

But anyway, either way I'm not sure how to see why it should have at most $d|n|$ edges.

If anyone could help that would be fantastic! :)

Comment: Why do you take the absolute value of $n$? Isn't $n$ positive anyway?

Comment: I actually have no idea why I put that, you're right of course.

Comment: If every *induced* subgraph has a vertex of degree at most $d,$ then *every* subgraph has a vertex of degree at most $d.$ That's because removing edges can only *decrease* the degree of a vertex.

Comment: Hint. If a finite graph $G$ is $d$-degenerate, then its vertices can be arranged in a sequence $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$ so that each vertex has at most $d$ neighbors to its right. From that it easily follows that the number of edges is at most $nd.$

Comment: Ah all is clear now thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

For a graph $G$ let $n(H)$ denote the number of vertices, $e(H)$ the number of edges. I assume that a graph must have at least one vertex

**Claim.** Let $d$ be a positive integer. If $G$ is a $d$-degenerate finite graph, then $e(G)\lt n(G)d.$

**Proof.** Assume for a contradiction that $e(G)\ge n(G)d.$ Among all induced subgraphs of $G,$ let $H$ be minimal with the property that $e(H)\ge n(H)d.$ (Recall that a graph must have at least one vertex; the "null graph" is not allowed.) Since $G$ is $d$-degenerate, we can choose a vertex $v\in V(H)$ so that $\deg_H(v)\le d.$ Now the induced subgraph $H-v$ has
$$e(H-v)=e(H)-\deg_H(v)\ge n(H)d-d=(n(H)-1)d=n(H-v)d,$$
contradicting the minimality of $H.$